# Problem with Mathf.Clamp and rotation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have a problem with my camera movement. I want to limit my camera rotation, but I don't know how to do this. I searched for a solution, but I was not able to find one.

In my current code, my camera rotates rapidly in any direction and I don't know how to implement the Mathf.Clamp correctly.

Here is my code:

```
public float rightSpeed = 20.0f;
public float leftSpeed = -20.0f;
public float rotationLimit = 0.0f;

void Update()
{
    //EdgeScrolling
    float edgeSize = 40f;
    if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width - edgeSize)
    {
        //EdgeRight
        transform.RotateAround(this.transform.position, Vector3.up, rotationLimit += rightSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.mousePosition.x < edgeSize)
    {
        //EdgeLeft
        transform.RotateAround(this.transform.position, Vector3.up, rotationLimit -= leftSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    rotationLimit = Mathf.Clamp(rotationLimit, 50f, 130f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RotateAround` method rotates **by** an angle. It doesn't assign the angle value you pass it. In this case I would suggest using a different approach. Instead of `RotateAround` method use the `eulerAngles` property and assign the rotation values directly.

## Example

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rightSpeed = 20.0f;
    public float leftSpeed = -20.0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        float edgeSize = 40f;
        
        if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width - edgeSize)
            RotateByY(rightSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        else if (Input.mousePosition.x < edgeSize)
            RotateByY(leftSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void RotateByY(float angle)
    {
        float newAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y + angle;

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
            transform.eulerAngles.x,
            Mathf.Clamp(newAngle, 50f, 130f),
            transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```